# String#replaceFirst not working seemingly randomly

Tags: java, regex

I have a string, which I try to replace the first appearance of %s.

For example:

```
"$%s".replaceFirst("%s", "10");
```

returns $10, but

```
"&cYou do not have %s!".replaceFirst("%s", "$10");
```

throws java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 1

I have print statements, I know 100% that is what is throwing the error, and that is what is going into the statement.

Comment: The `$` has a special meaning in regex. You must escape it

Comment: The second argument isn't Regex'd, it's only the first one. It still had a special meaning for some reason though.

Comment: It is regex'd in that `replaceFirst` passes the second parameter to `Regex::Matcher.replaceFirst`, which uses `$` as a reference to captured sub sequences

Comment: Weird, I tried putting \\Q and \\E before and after, which should ignore all special characters, but it didn't.

Comment: @Nick I did see that as an answer but because it is in the regex not the second argument I rejected it. The answer I accepted worked though.

Comment: @Big_Bad_E sure it is they are trying to replace `&#36;` with `$`

Comment: I did miss the updated answer and just read the top, you're correct.

Comment: Doesn't matter anyway - important thing is you got a good answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The replacement containing a `$` prefix is considered as group matcher (i.e. it tries to replace only matching group.

So the `$` needs to be escaped with `\\`:

```
System.out.println("&cYou do not have %s!".replaceFirst("%s", "\\$10"));
```

Comment: Yeah, no clue that existed, I just replaced "$" with "\\$". Thanks.